# Swing или JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Привет, использую **Swing** для создания графических приложений, наткнулся на **JavaFX**, многие пишут что **swing** уже очень старый и вообще деревня. Есть ли что-то в чем **Swing** лучше **JavaFX**? 
И много ли отличий? Если переходить на **FX** то никаких трудностей не будет если уверенно пишешь на **Swing**?

Comment: Мм, я когда начинал, то просто сравнил стиль написания примеров, выполняющих одинаковые функции и `javafx` показался мне намного удобнее, на нём и остановился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Java FX можно создать современный интерфейс. Принцип схож с Android. Интерфейс хранится в fxml- файлах или создаешь формы в коде. Также можно использовать css версии 2.2(вроде). В Scene Builder можно создавать макеты. Если небольшая функциональная прога, то проще обойтись Swingом.